# How to Mole SPFieldUser from SPField

Tags: unit-testing, moles

Im writing the unit test case using Moles for my SharePoint application
    I'm stuck up at the below lines of code I'm unable to type cast SPField to SPFieldUser.

```
SField subfield = list.Fields.GetField("Subscriber");
SPFieldUser userfield = (SPFieldUser)subfield;
userfield.SelectionGroup = web.Groups["Focal Points"].ID; //error line shown in pex

I'm getting "NullReference" exception at the above line
Can someone guide me here..
```

Comment: Please provide your tests. We kind of need to know how your moles are set up to confirm where the problem is as you have three potential points of failure on that one line alone. 

Which value is null? userField? web? web.Groups["Focal Points"] ?

Answer (score 0):

Although I am sure you have already checked these...:

1. Does GetField("Subscriber") return an object?
2. Does userfield get set to an object?
3. Is userfield.SelectionGroup null?
4. Try this syntax:

```csh
SPFieldUser userfield = subfield as SPFieldUser;
```

So, these all fail.  Let's examine covariance of SPFieldUser to SField.  The inheritance hierarchy is:

- System.Object

  - **Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField**

    - Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLookup

      - Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUser

Unfortunately, I do not have the Microsoft.SharePoint library, to see if the SPFieldLookup classis hiding something important in SPField.

Comment: To mock the above code, Ive written below line MSPFieldUSer user = subfield as MSPFieldUser...but Im getting invalid cast build error.If I dont use above line then during Pex Exploraitons im getting "Null reference" exception probably because SPFieldUser is not instantiated.. Any other way to debug\test above lines